# Duplicating event after event.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add ajax request on form submitting. And it works :)

But the problem is when I'm hitting `Submit` button second time - the event happens twice, and when I'm hitting button next time - the event happens three times and so on.

Why is it happening multiple times? Can't find any relative information.

```js
function saveActivityJobData(sender) {
    var elem = sender.parentNode.parentNode;
    $(elem).submit(function(event){
        console.log("form submitted!");
        event.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

Comment: Because i guess you are calling `saveActivityJobData()` multiple times (probably when the submit button is clicked), binding each time submit event. But because you don't provide any info as how you call this method, i'm just guessing...

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks, so stupid :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this syntax binds the function to the submit event,
$(elem).submit(func...)

check if you are calling saveActivityJobData function more than once,
every time you do you are binding another function to the submit event

you should only use the $(elem).submit, once to bind a function to the submit event

Comment: Yes, the problem is I'm binding handler multiple times - onclick, soo stupid

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

```
   function saveActivityJobData(sender) {
       var elem = sender.parentNode.parentNode;
        $(elem).submit(function(event){
          event.preventDefault();
          if (event.handled !== true) {
            event.handled = true;
            console.log("form submitted!");
          }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I don't tink it submits multiple time, try it https://jsfiddle.net/5akbt20o/ and explain why it should submit multiple time with this part of code?

Comment: Still you are binding a submit event in the browser at each call to the function. so, not a good approach at all. Sorry to say.